# How can I specify a bower dependency without pulling its dependencies?

Tags: bower

**Q:** Using *bower*, is there any way for me to declare my dependency on package ABC, so that bower will retrieve ABC for me **without retrieving ABC's own dependencies**?

I know this might sound like it misses the purpose of bower, which manages & pulls in all those cascading dependencies for us. Normally that's great. But for this one package ABC, I just need something from ABC but I do not want to be pulling in all its dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

Use `link` to point to package ABC from the project folder:

```
cd project
bower link foo
```